# Scapy Cannot find windows import

Tags: python, scapy

I've gone through reinstalled three different versions of python reinstalled

WinPCap
IPython
Scapy
LibDNet
MinGW
CYGen

And a few more. I cannot figure out how to remove the scapy error. I'm on Windows 10 using Python 2.7. Yes i've browsed other threads and yes I've read the readme files.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Rex>scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\\scapy", line 23, in <module>
    from scapy.main import interact
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    from windows import *
ImportError: No module named windows
```